# Discord python export an entire chat into .txt file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have researched far and wide and still haven't figured out a way to do this, what I basically want is for the bot after listening to a command, grab every message somebody has sent in the context channel and convert it into a .txt file, I don't even know if this is possible using python as I am  relatively new to the discord.py world, any help would REALLY be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Sp0t! Someone downvoted this, probably because the question is not specific enough. But it's still a good question and probably there are others out there that would like to have a simple solution. Problem is, there probably is none (hence too unspecific). But I googled around [and found this](https://github.com/Dracovian/Discord-Scraper). Isn't it something like this you're looking for? Good luck finding a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`channel.history()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=history#discord.abc.Messageable.history) in a for loop like so:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    filename = f"{ctx.channel.name}.txt"
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        async for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=None):
            file.write(f"{msg.created_at} - {msg.author.display_name}: {msg.clean_content}\n")
```

`entry` will be a [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) object so you'll be able to access it's author, content, mentions, ... However, due to API limitations, this method can be pretty slow with big channels so make sure to restrict this command.

PS: `msg.created_at` returns the message’s creation time in UTC. It's a `datetime.datetime` type so you'll be able to [format it with the `datetime` library](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime).